# inserting string in linked list c

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I am writing a program which will add string to list and print it (adding in loop and printing by function) but of course something goes wrong . This program is adding data but when i write ' 0 ' which means to stop adding, it dont want to stop.  I think i do something bad with allocating memory in add_to_list function. I looked in some topics but i have no clues how it should looks. I'd be glad if someone tell me what is wrong with that. :) There is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_L 30

typedef struct elem{
    char ch[MAX_L];
    struct elem *next;
    struct elem *prev;
}   list_elem;

void add_to_list (list_elem *first, char ch[MAX_L])
{
    list_elem *new=(list_elem*)malloc(sizeof(list_elem));
    new->ch[MAX_L]=ch;
    list_elem *tmp=first;
    while (tmp->next!=NULL){
        tmp=tmp->next;}
    tmp->next=new;
    new->prev=tmp;
    new->next=NULL;

}


void print_list(list_elem *first)
{
    first=first->next;
    if(first->ch==NULL)
    printf("lista jest pusta!!\n");
    while(first->next!=NULL){
    printf("%s\n",first->ch);
    first=first->next;}

}

int main()
{


    list_elem *first=(list_elem*)calloc(1,sizeof(list_elem));
    first->prev=NULL;
    first->next=NULL;

    char a;
    char ch[MAX_L];
    printf("write ' 0 ' to end program.\n");
    printf("write smth to add it to list: \n");
    while(ch!='0'){
        scanf("%s",&ch);
        add_to_list(first,ch);}
    print_list(first);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: You don't need to add a cast for `malloc()`.

Comment: so just  list_elem *new ?

Comment: `list_elem *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));` is Ok

Comment: `char ch[MAX_L]; ...; while(ch!='0')` - You cannot make the comparison you're trying to do in that `while` loop. `ch` is not a character, it's an array, so you're comparing some address in memory to the character `'0'` which is not what you mean to do. You might compare `ch[0] != '0'` instead.

Comment: mhm now it is working :D thanks a lot, i am really grateful

Comment: `if(first->ch==NULL)` :  `first->ch` never become NULL.

Comment: you don't need to first->prev=NULL and first->next=NULL since calloc will zero initialize memory for you, which means that those two pointers will already be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to arrays, try like this

```
strcpy(new->ch, ch);
```

instead of

```
new->ch = ch;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of `scanf("%s",&ch);` you should have `scanf("%s",ch);` as `ch` is an `char array`.
2. Also instead of `while(ch!='0')` you should use `strcmp` as again `ch` is an `char array` and not an ordinary character.